# Java file upload - inputstream issue

Tags: java, file-upload

I have to upload some files from jsp page, when i read the inputstream for the same.
I am checking for its authenticity that its a valid file or not, for that I am using [`jmimemagic`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmimemagic/)  and it takes input stream as argument and now when I am trying to upload it, its only uploading 1 byte of data?

I feel like there is some issue with inputstream any solution pls?

```
 //For checking the file type
InputStream loIns = aoFileStream.getInputStreamToReadFile();
            byte[] fileArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(loIns);
            mimeType = Magic.getMagicMatch(fileArray, true).getMimeType();
            if(!loAllowedFileTypesMimeList.contains(mimeType)){
                return false;
            }else{
                String lsFileName = aoFileStream.getFileName();
                String lsFileExt = lsFileName.substring(lsFileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
                if(loAllowedFileTypesList.contains(lsFileExt.toLowerCase())){
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            } 



// For uploading the content
File loOutputFile = new File(asFilePathToUpload);
            if(!loOutputFile.exists()){
                FileOutputStream loOutput = new FileOutputStream(loOutputFile);
                while (liEnd != -1) {
                    liEnd = inputStreamToReadFile.read();
                    loOutput.write(liEnd);
                }
                inputStreamToReadFile.close();
                loOutput.close();
            }
```

Comment: Can you please provide us with the code that you are using so that we can have a look? It is hard to diagnose without any error message or code.

Comment: in both the cases same stream is been used to perform actions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
 byte[] fileArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(loIns);
```

you've already exhausted your inputstream, so when you want to write it to a file, you should use the content of the `fileArray`, not your `loIns`:

```
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(loOutput, fileArray);
```

FileUtils is provided by apache-commons